# Trouble figuring out jquery selector to use

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, basically:

```
<form>
 <p class="comment-form-comment"> <textarea id="comment" ></textarea> </p>
    <p class="form-submit" style="display: none;"><input id="submit" value="submit" type="submit"></input> </p>
</form>
```

I have the following javascript:

```
jQuery('form').on('click','p.comment-form-comment', function(){

jQuery("p.form-submit").css('display', 'block');

    });​
```

The form is a looped item and I'm trying to select the submit button that belongs to the clicked textarea, instead of all of the buttons. I can't seem to wrap my head around it although it seems like it would be easy enough.

I set up a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJx3k/1/

Comment: `live()` is deprecated, you should be using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I updated, thanks. Any suggestions for my question?

Comment: Inside the .on() function try using $(this).parent().find("p.form-submit").  That ought to find the right element, but I don't have time to test it right now.

Comment: All were great answers that worked, thanks! I chose the one that suited my need best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('form p.comment-form-comment').click(function(){
    $(this).next('p.form-submit').show();
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('form').on('focus', 'textarea', function() {
    // hide other submit buttons
    jQuery('.form-submit').hide();

    // show the right one
    jQuery(this).closest('form').find('.form-submit').css('display', 'block');
});​
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/ZJx3k/6/**

Comment: Your code uses `on` (where your code doesn't work), while the fiddle uses `live` (where your code does work)...

Comment: @ianpgall Good catch. Since another answer was approved, I've changed the code to how I'd personally write it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery(this).find('p.form-submit')`

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJx3k/4/

You could use `jQuery.next()` as KaeruCT suggested, but then you would be relying on your HTML structure remaining the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.next()`

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJx3k/2/